# Google storage for each user

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I want to create application with consists of Desktop application and google cloud storage. So, each my client should have separate cloud storage. Does google provide such thing?

More info.
Because I do not know what can offer google app engine i wrote this question.
I need some database hosting for my desktop application. In future I think I will switch to GWT and app engine. I want to sell my application so each my client can't access my other client databases. I was thinking that would be safer if each client will have data in a separate database so I can't do some mistakes in code.

Comment: You need to provide more info on your senario.

Comment: Storage or Database? its not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can separate data in the datastore using namespaces on google app engine:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy

It's up to you to decide how to implement the namespaces.  You can separate them out by your user authentication system.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder per client and restrict the folder access to the user (works only with Google Accounts) or your can do the same with buckets, create a bucket per user (which might be an overhead if you have a lot of users).

---

For database AppEngine datastore has the ability to [separate the data by namespaces](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy). this doen't require any user account and its your responsibility to select with which namespace to work with per request.

Comment: I would rather not to use google accounts for authentication. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GAE namespace capability as pointed above by @dragonx without Google authentication.

Use a client name as a namespace identifier (needs to be unique) . How you fetch this client name is upto you. It can be stored in GAE itself if you wish or can be deciphered from the url used specific to a client.

Do have a look at the GAE multitenancy link https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/multitenancy/multitenancy

The example here can be easily adapted to use any string identifier per client.